# Java regex line.split("\\s*//")

Tags: java, regex, whitespace

I came across the following string split **line.split("\s*//")[0]** but can't seem find documentation on the use of the '/' character in regular expressions.

Here my code:

```
String line = "type=path.composition id=pathComp";
line = line.split("\\s*//")[0];

Console console = System.console();
System.out.println("This is the line: " + line);
```

Here the output:

```
This is the line: type=rule.composition id=ruleComp
```

I am wondering what exactly '/' does to the regular expression and was wondering whether anybody would be able to point me to some documentation and/or an answer highlighting what it does?

I also noticed that when I remove the '//' from the regex, the output changes to merely the first character, which I suppose makes sense given that \s* means that the expression spits on zero or more white space characters.

```
This is the line: t
```

This however raises the question: "what does the '//' add to the regular expression that sees the split occur at the end of the line"?

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Z

Comment: A `/` does nothing special and is taken literally; can you "read" `\s*//` and see what it means in the first place?

Comment: Hi fge. Thank you for this. I am not sure whether '/' would be taken literally though. It certainly permits reading the line to the end. If I remove the return value changes to 'This is the line:t'. What do you mean by "'read' \s*//"?

Comment: The regex `"\\s*//"` means "two forward slashes optionally preceded by whitespaces". Since your input string doesn't have any forward slashes, **the string is *not* split** and it is simply returned unchanged. As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) says: *If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your input text (`type=rule.composition id=ruleComp`), and your two regexes:

- regex 1: `\s*//`;
- regex 2: `\s*`.

When you try and `.split()` against a regular expression, the regex engine will try and match the regular expression (which is computed from the text literal as an argument) and these two things can happen:

- the regex cannot match anything (this is what happens with regex 1): the split effectively cannot operate and the 0th element is the input text;
- the regex can match an empty string (this is what happens with regex 2): in this case, the regex engine notices this and cannot let the situation continue, since otherwise it would result in and endless loop. Therefore it forcefully advances by one token before proceeding.

Hence your results:

- with the first regex, nothing is matched;
- with the second regex, an empty string is matched; the regex engine chooses to shift one character and considers the "discarded" text (the previous token) as the 0th match.

Comment: More precisely, the second regex will return this array: `new String[] {"t", "y", "p", "e", "=", "p", "a", "t", "h", ".", "c", "o", "m", "p", "o", "s", "i", "t", "i", "o", "n", "", "i", "d", "=", "p", "a", "t", "h", "C", "o", "m", "p"}`

Comment: @Andreas indeed; I was too lazy to fully expand :)

Comment: I was actually surprised that it returned an empty string where the space is. I'd have thought the regex to be greedy and the space plus the two empty strings around it would be a single separator.

Comment: @Andreas a regex engine may be greedy, but it will never try and seek beyond what it is actually satisfied with; this is why `\s*` matches an empty string, after all :)

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thank you all. And thank you fge. I now know what you meant!